# How can I use JSDoc to extends a documentation of a custom HTMLElement with new options for addEventListener type parameter?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I'm implementing a custom `HTMLElement` and I want to document it using *JSDoc* so I can have those *VS Code IntelliSense* fancy features, like when you are adding a event listener with `.addEventListener()` and VS Code helps you by showing all the available events.
I need to implement the same thing without overwriting the building documentation and only add new options to the the `type` parameter of `.addEventListener()`.
Relevant to state that I didn't overwrite the method.

I tried to use tags like `@name`, `@method` and `@memberof` but nothing seems to be working.
Here is an example:

```
/**
 * @name addEventListener
 * @method
 * @memberof Puzzle
 * 
 * @param {keyof HTMLElementEventMap | PuzzleEventKeyMap} type
 */
```